# I have a usb flash drive mounted in both sdb1 and sdb2. How to format it correctly?

Tags: filesystems, usb-device

I have a 4GB usb flash drive. When I plugged it on my debian linux I found that it mounted on both `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`. Each one detected as 2.5GB EFI System and 1.3GB Linux filesystem respectively. How do I format it correctly so it become one partition like 4GB FAT32?

Comment: Just unmount both partitions and format /dev/sdb. You can then repartition /dev/sdb to be one partition. Make sure to back up any precious data before hand.

Comment: @Peschke I did it with mkdosfs -n "DEVICENAME" -I /dev/sdb . it works. My usb drive detected as 4GB on /dev/sdb. However, i lost /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2 mount point. is it ok? or did i do something wrong?

Comment: @under5hell It is ok. If you execute `lsblk` you should see just one partition `/dev/sdb1` under `/dev/sdb/`. It may have changed `sdb` to `sdc`

Comment: mkdosfs is a sym for mkfs.fat, making a filesystem on the root disk will work but is not recommended. I'd advise creating a partition that spans the whole disk, then create the filesystem on this new partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to change the partition table you can use fdisk;

1. fdisk /dev/sdb
2. d = delete (delete until all current partitions are gone)
3. n = new
4. p = primary
5. 1 = 1st partition
6. just hit enter twice for the size (it will use the whole space)
7. t = type (change parition type)
8. 1 = partition number to change
9. b = win32 fat
10. w = write (write parition table to disk)

to create a new filesystem on the disk (this bit is the format / overwrite), use mkfs.

```
$ mkfs.fat /dev/sdb1
```

EDIT: changed from ext4 as an example to fat32.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use gparted for this kind of work

If not installed you can type for Debian-based distribution

```
apt-get install gparted
```

It has a gui, it is user-friendly and so pretty simple to use

It can handle a lot of format so it will certainly fit your needs.